# How to disable checkpoints in "fit" Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I writing module which sometimes (it can't be predicted) get new information. So i have only one example and 1 step for learn.

```
classifier = SKCompat(tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, 
                                            hidden_units=[7, 4, 2], 
                                            n_classes=2,
                                            optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.08)
                                                    )
                     )

INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into C:\Users\IVAN~1.KAP\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprit6vryq\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.71007, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.71007.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\Users\IVAN~1.KAP\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprit6vryq\model.ckpt-1
```

For every fit network create checkpoints. It takes 3-4 seconds. How i can disable it? It's too long for me

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `config` argument to DNNClassifier which is an instance of `RunConfig` and has `save_checkpoint_secs`/`save_checkpoint_steps` members which you can tune to change the frequency of saving.

Comment: If both `save_checkpoints_steps` and `save_checkpoints_secs` are None, then checkpoints are disabled.